# Difference of query results in BigQuery Python Client Library

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'd like to know the difference between query()'s return value and query().result()s'.

In BigQuery Python Client Library,

```
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
myQuery = "SELECT * FROM `mytable`"

## NOTE: This query result has just 1 row.
job = bigquery_client.query(myQuery)
for row in job:
    val1 = row

result = job.result()
for row in result:
    val2 = row

print(job == result) # False. I know QueryJob object is different to RowIterator object.
print(val1 == val2) # True
```

Why are val1 and val2 equivalent?
Can the values be different for a very large query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a yearlong self-answer.

Basically, 'job' and 'result' are different in my code.

bigquery_client.query() returns QueryJob instance.
( See https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.query )

But the QueryJob class has own _*iter*_ method and it returns iter(self.result())
( See https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/main/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py#L1778 )

So 'job' becomes an iterator of result() for the for-in loop.

Thus, job != result but val1 == val2.

Answer (score 0):

The query() method is used to execute SQL query.
BigQuery saves all the query results to a table which is either permanent or temporary.After a query finishes, the temporary table exists for up to 24 hours
and if we write the results to a new table it becomes a permanent table.

when writing a query result to a permanent table you can use the Python code which contains the result() method i. query().results() which is used to write the query data to a new permanent table.

so basically query() and query.results() gives the same output but in query().results() data fetched gets stored to a new table and in query() data resides in a temporary table.

As per you question val1==val2 you got true because data fetched by query() and query().results() are same but stored differently.

I am providing the public documentation link related to this.

[writing query results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results)