# Why the query result() difference when using Bigquery Python Client Library

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I am trying to figure out the difference when executing query via below 2 ways:

```
job1 = client.query(query).result()
```

vs

```
job2= client.query(query)
job2.result()
```

Code is below:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
bq_project= '<project_name>'
client = bigquery.Client(project=bq_project)

m_query = "SELECT * FROM <dataset.tbl>"

## NOTE: This query result has just 1 row.
x= client.query(m_query)
job1= x.result()

for row in job1:
    val1 = row

job2 = client.query(myQuery).result()
for row in job2:
    val2 = row

print(job1 == job2) # This is giving the return type as False
print(val1 == val2) # True
```

I understand that the final o/p from both the query execution will be same.

But I am not able to understand why `job1 is not equal to job2`.
Is the internal working different for both job1 and job2?

Note : I have gone through this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67465403/difference-of-query-results-in-bigquery-python-client-library) but the question there is different.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing two objects (or iterables), stored in different spots in the  memory. There is no point in comparing those. If you want to compare their contents, thats a doable thing:

```py
A = [each for each in job1]
B = [each for each in job2]

print(A == B)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do realize that comparison done is incorrect which is also not the intention of this question. I need to understand how .result() (internal working ) differ when written right after ``` client.query().result() ``` vs when it is written the other way ``` job = client.query() \n job.result() ``` Though i totally understand that .result() in both the cases will wait till the query is completed and the table is generated.